# ¿Por qué se le llama "bocadillo" a los elementos de la viñeta con los diálogos de los personajes?

Tags: etimología, vocabulario-técnico

El **bocadillo** o **globo** se define como el elemento de la viñeta de un cómic (o tebeo) o caricatura que contiene las intervenciones de los personajes. Durante años los dibujantes de cómics han ideado decenas de diversos métodos para representar las conversaciones o incluso los pensamientos de sus personajes en un medio visual.

[image: globos o bocadillos]

<sub>Fuente: http://spiramirabilis.cl</sub>

La forma predominante es la del óvalo, por lo que entiendo que al elemento gráfico se le llame "globo". Haciendo un poco de investigación, resulta que los antepasados de los "globos" o "bocadillos"

> tienen su antecedente en las filacterias (del griego «philakterion», ‘amuleto’), término que designaba a unas cintas que utilizaban los hebreos y que contenían textos de las Sagradas Escrituras, y posteriormente a las bandas incluidas en la pintura cristiana occidental que contenían textos.
>
> <sub>fuente: [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globo_(historieta))</sub>

Más adelante los caricaturistas desarrollaron el moderno "globo" con un contenido (el mensaje) y un continente (la forma exterior o silueta que presenta el *bocadillo*).

La RAE recoge esta acepción de [bocadillo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5iV6kp0) en la cuarta entrada del diccionario

> 4. m. En grabados, dibujos, caricaturas, chistes gráficos, tebeos, etc., espacio circundado por una línea en el que se contienen las palabras o pensamientos de un personaje.

pero para mí es completamente contraintuitivo este nombre (aunque lo haya usado por décadas sin reparar en ello). De hecho, recuerdo haberlo explicado alguna vez a alguien que esos óvalos con los diálogos de los personajes se llamaban "globos" (nadie protestaba por ello) o "bocadillos" (y la gente ponía cara rara). Así que estoy intentando encontrar la razón por la que este tipo de rotulación se le llama "bocadillo".

¿Por qué se le llama "bocadillo" a los elementos de la viñeta con los diálogos o pensamientos de los personajes?

Comment: Yo personalmente no había oído *bocadillo* para esto, pero me imagino que viene de la idea que el trocito de diálogo que se escribe en el globito es algo que *sale por la boca*.

Comment: La idea de bocadillo es la de algún tipo de relleno contenido entre dos panes. En este caso el relleno es el texto y los dos panes las líneas del globo. Esa es la idea que tengo yo en la cabeza, pero es algo que siempre me he preguntado, a ver qué respuestas se dan.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La cosa queda más clara si nos fijamos en la última acepción de *bocadillo*:

> **[bocadillo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5iV6kp0)**
>
> 9. m. Teatro. Intervención muy breve de un actor en una obra.

Es decir, si en mitad de una conversación un actor interviene de forma rápida y breve, a esa acción se le denominaba "bocadillo", claro símil a la comida breve que se introduce entre dos principales. Véase un ejemplo:

> *Era también Frasquito un excelente aficionado al arte escénico, y representó en distintos teatros caseros papeles principales en Flor de un día y La trenza de sus cabellos. Aún recordaba parlamento y bocadillos de ambas obras, que repetía con énfasis declamatorio, y que Obdulia oía con arrobamiento, arrasados los ojos en lágrimas, dicho sea con frase de la época.*
>
> Benito Pérez Galdós, "Misericordia", 1897 (España).

Los diálogos en los cómics son muy similares a los de una obra de teatro, por lo que no es raro que en algún momento se aplicara el mismo sentido de "bocadillo" a los diálogos de los personajes en aquellos.

Answer (score 2):

La forma del bocadillo de comer y de la figura gráfica es similar:

[image]
([fuente](https://static-blogs.larioja.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/49/2017/09/falsaria1386265365iberico.jpg))

También, se ha señalado la acepción teatral breve o el que sale de la boca. En España, es habitual llamarlo bocadillo.